# What does "at the threshold" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence actually mean: "At the threshold of neutrino astronomy".

Comment: What do dictionaries etc say? I suggest [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-threshold-of-sth).

Comment: @androidcodehunter are you referring to [this](http://gmatclub.com/forum/virtually-everything-astronomers-known-about-objects-outside-76197.html)?

Comment: Yes, it is a title and in the description part it describes how neutrino created with certain technology. I think the above sentence means "at the verge of inventing neutrino". Is my comprehension right?

Comment: @androidcodehunter Not inventing, neutrino astronomy is about studying the universe using neutrinos.  Not inventing them.  But yes verge or edge can substitute for threshold.

Comment: Yes, I am refering your provided article @CandiedOrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the threshold of neutrino astronomy

Is a possible title for the passage given [here](http://www.litesee.com/verbal/verbal/reading/reading-passage8.htm) or [here](http://gmatclub.com/forum/virtually-everything-astronomers-known-about-objects-outside-76197.html)

Threshold is being used to mean the latest technology.  This might not be obvious from the typical definitions you might find for threshold.  It's use here is slightly artful.

The most literal definition is:

> threshold - a strip of wood, metal, or stone forming the bottom of a doorway and crossed in entering a house or room.<sup>[G1](https://www.google.com/search?q=threshold&oq=threshold&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)</sup>

But this can be taken as using a more metaphorical meaning closer to:

> threshold - the magnitude or intensity that must be exceeded for a certain reaction, phenomenon, result, or condition to occur or be manifested.
>   "nothing happens until the signal passes the threshold"<sup>[G2](https://www.google.com/search?q=threshold&oq=threshold&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)</sup>

Either way it's expressing a boundary. It's meant to fire your imagination with the possible discoveries that will be made once we cross it.

The other answers are not actually wrong but they tend to focus on smaller parts of the passage.

Answer (score 0):

> At the threshold of neutrino astronomy

It's likely that this meant

> on the frontier of neutrino astronomy

*frontier*: An undeveloped area or field for discovery or research

Answer (score 0):

"the threshold", the door, the entrance, the beginning. The author means we are at the beginning of neutrino astronomy and uses a literary device, a kind of metaphor.